# How to debug why an HTML element has certain properties

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This is a novice question about how to debug HTML layout.

I have made a webpage. I am looking at it in the browser. An element is bigger than I expected -- to be exact, it has a greater width. Is there a way to ask the browser, which decided to render it at the width I am seeing, *why* it has that particular width?

That is, is there a way for me to ask the browser (e.g., Chrome) to show me *exactly and only* the set of CSS properties, other elements, and other constraints which contributed to computing the value which I am observing?

Comment: I think that Chrome developer tools (shortcut F12) is enough for your purpose. Try to search for some tutorials, like [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css) or others. Basically, with it you can see the style of a tag and who set it (which css file or if itìs an inline style)

Comment: Doesn't seem to help in my case. I'm looking at the width of a TD cell in a TABLE, and in the developer tools, under the Elements/Styles pane, after I select the TD, it just says width 2160px without saying why. It seems like external CSS is not contributing. It's just the natural behavior of TABLE given its content. Is there a way to drill deeper into the logic underlying the width?

Comment: If you post the page you're examining it's easier, but if you see only the effective width you need to check td layout, others td width and layout, parents layout and width. Eg.[here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_fancy), table width is 100%, the effective width of a single td is proportional to a column max-content, if you put the same content in every td you'll see that width become 1/3 of total for everyone.As a last thing you need also to consider default logic of the specific browser, so you need to check many things.

Answer (score 1):

You can **inspect** (ctrl + shift + I) to see all the properties regarding your html document. Inspect using the mentioned command and from the options given on top click on **Elements**. There you find all the elements present in your HTML document. Choose the element you want to explore.After choosing the element on the right side you will see different css applied to the selected element. You will see the class and attributes in it. Beside the class the **file name** to which class belongs will also be mentioned. When you scroll down at the bottom you will find the **box model** of the element choosen. It will show margin outside it, padding inside it, border around it and where it is positioned.Other then that, there is different effect you can check by clicking on **:hov** on the top.There you find **"Force element state"**. When you check **:hover** from those options you see how the choosen element will look on hover. Same implements for the other options. You can use **filter** on top beside :hov to filter class containing a certain attribute by typing the attribute in  filter. Under filter you find  **element.style** where you can apply different css properties to the choosen element by typing the attributes and their value in element.style.

I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I've gotten as far as this, but the width is not coming from CSS. It must be coming from the default logic that governs how a TABLE's TD's width is determined. It doesn't seem like Chrome tells you how it does that, in the same way that it will tell you which CSS style declaration is applied.

Comment: you can try to set width in element.style after choosing the element. If it set the width to the desired pixels then it is surely coming from some css. If it's default(which i don't think it should be) you will not be able to apply attributes from element.style either. Also try using !important like this (width : 200px!important).